# $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \exp\{\lambda((q+pe^t)-1)\}$

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \exp\{\lambda((q+pe^t)-1)\}$$

How do I do this? Do I use the chain rule?

$$= \exp\{\lambda((q+pe^t)-1)\} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} (\lambda((q+pe^t)-1)) \\
= \exp\{\lambda((q+pe^t)-1)\} \lambda pe^t$$

But the solution appears to be without the $e^t$ term? (see last line of image below)

> We have $$\begin{align}M_X(t)&=\Bbb E[e^{Xt}]\\
> &=\Bbb E[\Bbb E[e^{Xt}|Y]]\\
> &=\Bbb E[(q+pe^t)^Y]\\
> &=\sum_{y=0}^\infty(q+pe^t)^y\dfrac{\lambda^ye^{-\lambda}}{y!}\\
> &=\exp\{\lambda((q+pe^t)-1)\}.
> \end{align}$$Differentiating$$\dfrac{\mathrm dM_x(t)}{\mathrm dt}=\exp\{\lambda((q+pe^t)-1)\}\lambda p.$$

Comment: Your result is the correct one.

Comment: If user Adobe is watching this thread: your edit was approved because it replaced an image with MathJax, but in the future please do not change notation (adding `\mathrm` to each $d$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I do this? Do I use the chain rule?

Yes, exactly, you use the chain rule. And your result is correct, the official solution has mistakenly forgotten the $e^t$ term from the outer $\exp$'s argument.